# ¿Como "concatenar" o unir múltiples arrays con cada elemento dentro de los arrays?

Tags: python

no soy experta en python, estaba aprendiendo matlab y los comandos de aqui los quisiera transformar a python, pero no se como...
Tengo diferentes arrays en python:

```
LivAgs=["Liv1000","Liv1014","Liv1030","Liv1041","Liv1076","Liv1083"]
RegAgs=["Reg1000","Reg1014","Reg1030","Reg1041","Reg1076","Reg1083"]
varnames=["Tmaxcdo_","Tmincdo_","ClimdailyTasmax_","ClimdailyTasmin_","HTanual_"]
```

quisiera unir a través de un ciclo o no se si con alguna funcion de python (no se si exista alguna), para que me dé algo como esto:

```
varnames2=[Tmaxcdo_Liv100, Tmaxcdo_Liv1014,Tmaxcdo_Liv1030,Tmaxcdo_Liv1041,Tmaxcdo_Liv1076,Tmincdo_Liv1000,Tmincdo_Liv1014.,HTanual_Liv1000,HTanual_liv...]
```

y asi con cada uno de los varnames de mi matriz de Liv y de Reg, 
podrían ayudarme??he estado buscando ya algun tiempo y no encuentro algo parecido, solo el np.append pero no hace lo que yo quiero , ayuda por favor :( en esta pandemia! 
saludos

Answer (score 3):

Pareciera que lo que buscas es iterar sobre cada `varnames` y en cada caso concatenar sus elementos con cada valor de las listas `LivAgs` y `RegAgs`. Algo así:

```
LivAgs=["Liv1000","Liv1014","Liv1030","Liv1041","Liv1076","Liv1083"]
RegAgs=["Reg1000","Reg1014","Reg1030","Reg1041","Reg1076","Reg1083"]
varnames=["Tmaxcdo_","Tmincdo_","ClimdailyTasmax_","ClimdailyTasmin_","HTanual_"]

newlist = []
for v in varnames:
  for a in LivAgs + RegAgs:
    newlist.append(v + a)
```

Finalmente los valores los tedrás en la nueva lista `newlist`, es posible usar comprensión de listas para simplificar bastante el código:

```
newlist = [v + a for v in varnames for a in LivAgs + RegAgs]
```

Por cierto, si hablas de un `array` de `numpy`, simplemente transforma cada uno de estos en una lista, por ejemplo:

```
newlist = [v + a for v in varnames.tolist() for a in LivAgs.tolist() + RegAgs.tolist()]
```

Comment: Hola, sí buscaba eso aunque en realidad mi duda iba más para poder cargar muchas variables que tengo en un archivo .mat de matlab, y según yo hice esos arrays para poder cargarlos de "jalón" sin tener que estar cargando  variable por variable pero no funcionó :(